# SQL-Fiddle doesn't show spaces correctly

Tags: whitespace, sqlfiddle

A query like this:

```
;with t as (
    select 1 id, 'Name 1' [name]
    union all select 2,' Name 2 '
)
select 
    [name], '{'+[name]+'}', '     ' + [name], '                     ' + [name], '{     ' + [name]+ '}'
from t;
```

should have an output like this:

```
Name 1   |{Name 1}   |     Name 1   |                     Name 1  |{     Name 1}
 Name 2  |{ Name 2 } |      Name 2  |                      Name 2 |{      Name 2 }
```

but SQLFiddle shows it in different format as you can see below:
[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/9231)

I think problem is related to HTML specs that skip multiple whitespaces.

Comment: Yes, most HTML renderers will collapse multiple spaces into a single one. What exactly is the question or problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: Yes, there does appear to be a whitespace stripping problem with SQLFiddle.  But why does this matter to you?

Comment: I ask this question from [jake-feasel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/808921/jake-feasel) ;).

Answer (score 1):

It does appear that excess whitespace is being removed in SQLFiddle query output.  But assuming you are planning to run your queries from SSMS this should not be a problem.  If you are actually planning to exchange formatted information using Fiddle, but it won't work as expected, you could try using another SQL demo tool such as Rextester:

## Demo

I have tested your query in Rextester and your whitespace appears to be preserved.

Comment: Thanks, about that alternative tool ;).